# shell script - filter link with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell, filter

I need advice with regular expression. I have some .txt file, where is scraped website. In scraped file(website) are some links which I need copy to another .txt file, every record(link) in new file on new line. In scraped .txt file is everything on one line(without spaces where aren't needed) and I don't know how mix regular expression. I looking everywhere but nothing with this combination I didn't find.

.txt file:

```
some"text href="www.links123.eu/asdci"anothertext.a href="www.nextlink.net"moretext
```

OUTPUT:

> [www.links123.eu/asdci](http://www.links123.eu/asdci)

> [www.nextlink.net](http://www.nextlink.net)

here is the scraped .txt file: [enter here](http://leteckaposta.cz/244391896)

Comment: Is there really no space before the first `href`?

Comment: Why don't you extract hyperlinks from the .txt with the full content of the scraped website, rather than this condensed format?

Comment: no... it"s my mistake, before first `href` is space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about:

```
grep -oP '\"http.*?\"' index.txt | tr -d '"'
```

you must have Gnu grep, perhaps replace `grep -P` with `pgrep`

output:

```
...
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/car/?hl=es-la
https://scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fac97a99c1a1b8acba2d00036f5f6630/5B5C3121/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c135.0.810.810/30078343_772016273004298_5639967572104314880_n.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for awk (or cut).  You want to use the `"` as a separator and then take the 3rd and 5th entries:

```
echo 'some"text href="www.links123.eu/asdci"anothertext.a href="www.nextlink.net"moretext' | awk -F '"' '{print $3"\n"$5}'
```

Output:

```
www.links123.eu/asdci
www.nextlink.net
```

Comment: maybe it's work on this code but whet i try used it on website. it doesn't work

Comment: Then you need to add more examples.  I gave an answer which works with every case you provided.